# Avoid repetitive coding when disposing of objects

Tags: c#, repository-pattern, dispose, non-repetitive

With a purpose of memory optimization we've been adding these lines of code:

```
public class Whatever: IDisposable

private bool disposed = false;

protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (!this.disposed)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            context.Dispose();
        }
    }
    this.disposed = true;
}

public void Dispose()
{
     Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

To every single of our repositories, then are updating tests for each repo as well.
I am wondering, since copy+paste isn't really encouraged in coding isn't there a better way to implement this? Especially annoying since, depending on a project, we have 10-40 repositories...

Comment: What is `context`? Also, why would this help with memory optimization?

Comment: Context is database connection. 
Someone at some point found an article like this
https://forums.asp.net/t/2090002.aspx?Proper+way+to+Dispose+my+object+when+using+Repository+patterns
 I imagine and has decided to implement this.

Comment: have you tried implementing this _once_ in a common base class?

Comment: No, an idea of a sort I am looking for from more experienced people than myself :D. How would that look like?

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps simpler - use the `context` itself to track disposal:

```cs
protected virtual void Dispose(bool disposing)
{
    if (disposing) context?.Dispose();
    context = null;
}

public void Dispose()
{
     Dispose(true);
     GC.SuppressFinalize(this);
}
```

Note that I also think it is *vanishingly* unlikely that you have a finalizer involved here (and if you do, that is probably a big mistake), so honestly: you can simplify further:

```cs
public void Dispose()
{
    context?.Dispose();
    context = null;
}
```

Comment: Should this be in a separate class or in the context file? We have only one context and are calling different database tables in each class.

Comment: @EmilijaVilijaTrečiokaitė in the version of the code in the question: you disposed the context in this type - I'm simply preserving that exact same semantic from your original question, but: with simpler code; any questions about lifetimes are entirely up to you and your design - I haven't changed that in any way; the code I've posted would simply be a replacement for where-ever your code currently appears

Answer (score 1):

To expand on the base-class approach that [Franz hints at](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69221484/avoid-repetitive-coding-when-disposing-of-objects/69221782#comment122346441_69221484); something like:

```cs
// common base class that handles the shared details
public abstract class MyCommonBase : IDisposable
{
    protected SomeContext Context { get; private set; }

    public MyCommonBase(SomeContext context)
        => Context = context ?? throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(context));

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        // your choice of dispose code here, via Context
    }
}

// specific implementation class
public class MySomething : MyCommonBase
{
    public MySomething(SomeContext context) : base(context) {}

    // your *extra* code here; can read Context from base
}
```

Note that in `MySomething` you don't need to deal with any of the disposal bits - that's all handled by the base class (although you can still `override` the `Dispose()` method to add *additional* cleanup features).

Comment: I'll try this, thanks!

Comment: Follow up - unit tests for the disposing, should they be written for the base class, or rather in each of the repositories?

Comment: @EmilijaVilijaTrečiokaitė I have no opinion whatsoever on that